# Microsoft Graph API Work Accounts authorize with Note.Read scope need admin approval

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onenote

I am trying to use Microsoft Graph API V2.0 to access user's OneNote Notebooks.

I am trying to authorize via OAuth using the follow link sample:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
    response_type=code
    &client_id={id}
    &redirect_uri={url}
    &scope=Notes.Read%20offline_access
    &state={state}
```

When I login with a work account I get a message saying that:

> {app_name} needs permission to access resources in your organisation that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.

And:

> Message: AADSTS90094: The grant requires admin permission.

Using an admin account I have no problems.

From [Notes permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#notes-permissions), none of Note scopes (i.e. `Notes.Read`, `Notes.ReadWrite`, `Notes.Create` or `Notes.ReadWriteAll`) *require Admin Consent*.

Is there any reason for this to request admin permissions?

Comment: Can you add the manifest for your app's registration (you can get this from either the Azure Portal or `apps.dev.microsoft.com`, depending on where you registered)?

Comment: which part in particular do you need? I can authorize using [Files Permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#files-permissions) for example

Comment: The manifest is a JSON representation of your app's registration (i.e.. your AppId, Name, etc.). You can get it from either the Azure Portal or https://apps.dev.microsoft.com (depending on where you registered your app).

Comment: Is [this](https://gist.github.com/ruirodrigues-eyenov/4cd8890117e8140377a57c84940812a8) enough?

Comment: Is this happening regardless of the AD tenant you attempt to authenticate against? I'm wondering if the AD tenant has disabled the "Users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf" option.

Comment: No, there were users from another AD tenant that were able to login. And yes, the one failing to authorize has that option disabled. But authorizing with File.ReadWrite (to access OneDrive) works normally, as well as when using ADAL SDK (different application though)

Comment: If they've disabled that option, they've basically blocked any users from consenting on their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs when the Azure AD instance/tenant has disabled "Users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf". This is a global User Setting in Azure AD:

[image]

When this option is set to `No`, user's will be blocked from executing the [User Consent](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-user-vs-admin/) flow:

[image]

To get around this, an Admin will either need to consent on the User's behalf or they need to re-enable the User Consent option (this is the recommended solution, there are few rational reasons to entirely turn off User Consent).

Comment: Thanks for you response. I thought that having that disabled was not the problem here because none of the [Delegated Notes permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#notes-permissions) need Admin Consent. Any reason why it works with `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/authorize` endpoint? And why this is not a problem when using just [Files permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#files-permissions) ?

Comment: Are you saying this AppId works with `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/authorize` but not `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`? Or do you mean a different App Id?

Comment: Sorry, different App Id. The one that works with `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/authorize` is not register for `v2.0` endpoint (mixing up things in here maybe)

Comment: Apps registered with v1 in your own tenant will behave differently. This blocks users from authorizing external (multi-tenant) applications, internal apps created by a tenant admin are already authorized.

Comment: Ok, Thanks! Just one last question, why [Notes](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#notes-permissions) require _Admin Permissions_ and [Files](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#files-permissions) don't?

Comment: They're separate APIs build by separate product teams. Each underlying product defines their own permission scopes and restrictions.  These decisions can be impacted by regulations, security threat analysis, or even legacy API behaviors so as to not overly disrupt existing developers.

Answer (score 0):

We wrote a detailed article dealing with the [need admin approval issue](https://appfluence.com/help/article/microsoft-teams-need-admin-approval/), addressing the most common situations. I suspect the problem is addressed in the first section, and your IT admin needs to allow users to request access.